# Causing type conversion of a GORM field to fail validation

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a grails domain class with an Integer property such as:

```
class MyDomainClass {

    Integer i

    static   constraints = {
        i(min: 0, max 5, 
            validator: {
                // Something that fails when type conversion was used.
            }
    }
}
```

If i is set to a non-integer, e.g., 3.1 it will set i to 3 due to type conversion. But what I want to do is to either disable type conversion for i, or preferably fail validation when was originally set via type conversion.

Note: I want this to work both via explicit setting of the value, and via the default properties constructor.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

In your cusom validator you should be able to access the original value of `i` from the request parameters. To do this you'll first need to get the current `HttpServletRequest`. There's a Spring/Grails helper class that allows you to get the current request from anywhere, though this is not a particularly recommended practice

You can then test yourself whether this value is really an Integer, e.g.

```
static   constraints = {
    i(min: 0, max 5, 
        validator: {
            try {
                def originalValue = getRequestParam('i')
                return true
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                return false
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Do validator really have access to `params`  if called from a controller? What will happen when it's called from another context where no request is available?

Comment: @Antoine no they don't have acees to `params`, I don't know what I was thinking. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

By the time validator is executed value is already casted.

I think the easiest way is to create a custom setter.
In custom setter you may take the value, do with it what you want and if it is not an Integer throw an error. You can even simulate validation exception if you want.

This approach should cover all your use cases, unless you are explicitly accessing the field of the class by using .@ operator.

EDIT:
you will have to make sure, that in your controller you are not doing:

```
params.getInteger('paramName')
```

because the cast might happen in there, and even your custom setter won't help.